# net/http: TLS handshake timeout on minikube Windows 7

Tags: docker, kubectl, minikube

I am trying to setup minikube on my local machine with windows 7 with virtual box.

I tried to follow up the below steps

[image]

I also tried passing proxy with below command

```
minikube start --docker-env http_proxy=http://xxx:80 --docker-env https_proxy=http://xxx:80 --docker-env no_proxy=192.168.99.100
```

I am getting net/http: TLS handshake timeout  on minikube
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOX4Y.png)

I have tried kubectl v1.9 , v1.3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to see the IP address using `minikube ip`, then check if you have an exception in your no proxy shell environment by using the `set` command. If not please set it as `set NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1, 192.168.99.100` where `192.168.99.100` is the IP returned by the `minikube ip` command. This works for me.

Comment: minikube ip  retuns the ip 192.168.99.100 .Then i tried doing set NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,192.168.99.100" . Then i tried minikube dashboard command which returns "Could not find finalized endpoint being pointed to by kubernetes-dashboard: Erro
r validating service: Error getting service kubernetes-dashboard: Get https://19
2.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard: n
et/http: TLS handshake timeout"

Answer (score 0):

## start minikube on vitual box with below command

$minikube start --kubernetes-version="v1.4.0" --vm-driver="virtualbox" --docker-env http_proxy="http://xxx:yyy" --docker-env https_proxy="http://xxx:yyy" --show-libmachine-logs --alsologtostderr

## try minikube dashboard if still giving above error: net/http: TLS handshake timeout on minikube Windows 7

$minikube ip

$SET NO_PROXY="127.0.0.1,[ip_of_above_result]"

Try setting cluster context with skip to TLS verification

$kubectl config set-cluster minikube-vpn --server=https://127.0.0.1:8443 --insecure-skip-tls-verify

$kubectl config set-context minikube-vpn --cluster=minikube-vpn --user=minikube

$kubectl config use-context minikube-vpn

## now try to test with  command,

minikube dashboard

## it should automatically trigger opening web page of kubernetes

## To add on above , version played crucial for me. I downgraded minikube from latest v0.25.2 to v0.24.0([minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v0.24.0)) and kubectl 1.10(latest [kubectl](https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.10.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe)) and --kubernetes-version="v1.9.4"(latest)